# App widget is not generating the route | firebase signup

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Upon successful signup, I am trying to send users to the homepage `(home)` explaining how to use the app. I am doing so through this code block on my `signup.dart`

```
onPressed: () async {
          try {
            User user =
                (await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: _emailController.text,
              password: _passwordController.text,
            ))
                    .user;
            if (user != null) {
              user.updateProfile(displayName: _nameController.text);
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.home);
            }
          }
```

Which is pointing to the `home` route

```
class AppRoutes {
  AppRoutes._();

  static const String authLogin = '/auth-login';
  static const String authSignUp = '/auth-signup';
  static const String home = '/home';

  static Map<String, WidgetBuilder> define() {
    return {
      authLogin: (context) => Login(),
      authSignUp: (context) => SignUp(),
      home: (context) => Home(),
    };
  }
}
```

However, when I sign up, the data is rendering in firebase, but the user is not being sent to the `home` page, and throws this error in my console

```
Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate
this route.
Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
 1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
 2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
 3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
 4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
```

Any thoughts on how to rectify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added `onGenerateRoute` in your `MaterialApp`?  Like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
      initialRoute: yourRoute,
      child: YouApp(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Router {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case AppRoutes.home:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Home());
      case AppRoutes.authLogin:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Login());
      case AppRoutes.authSignUp:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignUp());
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                      child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}')),
           ));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```